# What song did the Cracher-Mortel hum/sing during "The Waking Dead"?

Tags: grimm

During the Grimm episode *The Waking Dead,* the villain of the week [hummed and occasionally sang](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sH99YuC-_9A) a song.

- What song was it? (Bonus points for audio link.)
- If there's a particular reason for the song (either that he was humming at all, or why that particular song was used), that'd be really cool to know too.

Comment: I wasn't planning to watch this week's episode yet, but did so just to see if I could answer this. Unfortunately I really don't have a clue so I'm hoping somebody else will be able to shed some light on it.

Comment: I really struggle to make out the words between his accent and the volume, but it definitely contains "Bonsoir", "danse", and "beaucoup".  Google doesn't immediately come up with a good match for that.

Comment: This is driving me and my wife a little crazy, but we still haven't been able to figure it out.  Haven't found anything useful yet, not even what language the villain speaks (I'm *assuming* Cajun ...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can sometimes find it in music credits, however I found this answer when googling the search terms "grimm the waking dead music"

http://www.tunefind.com/show/grimm/season-2/14636

It is identified "Bon Soir Dame", I believe originally by Ed Ames,

However youtube also shows several recordings by folk groups such as the Sandpipers and others (Search Bon Soir Dame).

As far as the danse/beaucoup, those are French, which is spoken by many Cajuns and could be a French version of the song or the characters own addition.

Comment: Thanks, though I swear I did that google search a dozen times (probably before that post was made or indexed).